# Cannot get ASP.NET Restful API working on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, api, iis

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Restful API and have followed [this link](http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish.aspx) pretty much exactly (except converting it to VB.NET and changing the controller name, etc.)

I have published the API on my Windows 2008 R2 Server (running IIS-7.5) exactly like the example but can't seem to get it to work.

It doesn't matter what I try, I continually get 404 Errors, both locally on the IIS server and from any remote machine.

I have scoured the net trying to apply every kind of resolution I can find, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

I am connecting using ASP.NET 4.0 as my application pool using framework 4.5.2

Hoping someone could shed some light on exactly what I need to look for.

Comment: There are a lot of details missing from your question, but one thing might be that your controller action is requiring authentication and you are not providing any. You might try adding a [AllowAnonymous] attribute on your controller action and see if it lets you through.

Comment: @randyh22 sorry I do understand that details were missing.  But I didn't know exactly what detail I needed to put up.  The attached link shows all of the code that I have used as I copied it exactly as demonstrated.

Comment: Add web.config and route configuration details.

Comment: 404 = file not found so maybe you have the URL wrong. So go into IIS, go to your virtual directory, go to content view then right click on a file (preferably a static picture) and browse. Does it work? If so take note of the resulting URL and compare it to the URL's you are using. See anything strange? How are you actually trying? Have you written a client? using a test client? or are you just typing URL's into a browser? Can you get to the wsdl page?

Comment: Okay, I have redone the example again, this time not converting it or changing anything.  I can now browse to the WebSite on the IIS server which returns results and I can remotely connect to the root directory of the server from my PC (showing the IIS home page), but I still get a 404 when accessing the full path (http://myserver:81/api/customer/getallcustomers).

Comment: Fixed.  I had setup my WebSite on the same port as I was hosting IIS.  Chaning the port number now allows me to remote connect to return data.